# codeigniter where to put common js php code

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, project-layout

I have a site developed in codeigniter.
In many page of my site I have more equal function javascript/jquery with some string in PHP like this:

```
function change_city_by_nation(nation_id){
        var site_url_city ="<?php echo(site_url('/backend/city/get_city_by_nation_id')); ?>";
        $.ajax({   
            url: site_url_city, 
            async: false,
            type: "POST", 
            data: "nation_id="+nation_id, 
            dataType: "html", 

            success: function(data) {
                $('#city').empty();
                $(data +' option').each(function(index){
                    $('#city').append($(this).html());
                });
                $('#city').prepend("<option value='0' selected='selected'>Tutte le città</option>");
            }
         });
    }
```

Where is the best place to collect all this javascript function with some string in php?
- JS file (but I have to pass the php string when I call it)
- Helper (but how?)
- file php where declare the function JS like common.php(but where to put it and how to call it?)

Have you some solution for my scope?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to group those scripts, you can make a regular .js file but with modified function parameters - make all the values sent by PHP actually become function parameters.
So, for example,

`function change_city_by_nation(nation_id){...}`

becomes

`function change_city_by_nation(url_from_php, nation_id){...}` etc...

And of course, you need to modify the function bodies and function calls (from the views) afterwards.

However, if you have a function that is used only on a single page, it's perfectly acceptable to leave the JS function there, and embed the PHP values just like you did in your example.

Comment: Thanks I thinked that this is the more pratical way for my purpose. Thanks for the answer +1

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat common practice to create a JS variable in your `<head>` (or somewhere before your main JS file) that refers to a base URL, or other common variables needed by JS that are generated by the back end.

```
<script>
var SITE_URL = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

Then, your Javascript file would be included at the end of your `<body>` HTML source, and it can utilize these variables where necessary.

How you generate the initial variables will depend on how you handle templates in your application. A common header / footer will make the whole process easier.